# Cannot fetch record using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to fetch record from a MySQL database using PHP. Here is my code.

user.php:

```
require_once ('../../include/dbconfig.php');
require_once ('common.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$userClass=new CommonConnectorFuncs();
$redata=$userClass->insertUserRecordForSignup();
echo $redata;exit;
```

common.php:

```
require_once ('../../include/dbconfig.php'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
$imagepath=$protocol. "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/connector/upload/";
class CommonConnectorFuncs{
     function __construct() {

    }
    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }
    public function insertUserRecordForSignup(){
        $sql=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from cn_user_info order by user_id desc");
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to fetch record and print through class but it's throwing the below message.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: connect in common.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in common.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in common.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: data in common.php on line 20
```

Those query is working fine inside the `user.php` file but it's not working in `common.php` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: `$connect` isn't visible inside your class.

Comment: use `global $connect;` or parse the variable `connect` as a parameter

Comment: no, DONT use global $connect.. pass in the variable properly

Comment: How to make this correct.

Comment: Pass it as an argument to the constructor, and make it a variable of the class. Then use it as `$this->connect` inside the class (instead of `$connect`), if you've done it properly.

Comment: agree with @DevDonkey I do not see the benefit to using $connect as global. Your function depends on a mysqli connection in order to work, so just make the connection a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, this is a scoping issue. Specifically, $connect is not in scope.

> Notice: Undefined variable: connect in common.php on line 16 
>   **where connect is not defined anywhere.**

Moreover, It's exactly as the error states as you're passing arguments to mysqli_query incorrectly. Assumming  $connect is your mysqli connection generated at some point by `new mysqli()` it should be:

```
$sql = "select * from cn_user_info order by user_id desc";
$result = mysqli_query( $connect,$sql) or die('Could not look up user information; ' . mysqli_error($connect))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wait, you're querying the result of a query? You sure about this? :p

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in that you are trying to access a `global` variable within a `function`.

First of all, make sure you `include` the php file with the relevant database connection. And as you are trying to access a global variable there are two ways to achieve this.

**Method 1**

Create a `global` variable at the top of the function.

```
global $connect;
```

But as [Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/2408342) says in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585645/can-not-fetch-record-using-php-and-mysql/43585770#comment74220581_43585770), it is a bad practise, so I'd suggest the next.

**Method 2**

Pass the connection to the function's parameters.

```
public function insertUserRecordForSignup($connect){
    $sql=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from cn_user_info order by user_id desc");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
         $data[]=$row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: @satya what is the path of the php file where you have created the database connection `mysqli_connect()`?

Comment: here is the code `$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "******", "connector");` and path is correct .

Comment: @satya try my new answer

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala **No**, using the `global` keyword is bad practice, and should be avoided. Pass it as an argument instead.

Comment: I do not see the benefit to using $connect as global. Your function depends on a mysqli connection in order to work, so just make the connection a function parameter

Comment: @ShashankShah Sorry, my mistake!

Comment: dont even mention putting a global var inside a class.. Id sack someone for continuing to do that

Answer (score 0):

Make the connect variable a property of your class as by parsing it in your construct function

```
require_once ('../../include/dbconfig.php');
require_once ('common.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$userClass=new CommonConnectorFuncs($connect);
$redata=$userClass->insertUserRecordForSignup();
echo $redata;exit;
```

In your class,

```
class CommonConnectorFuncs{
    var $Connection; 
     function __construct($connection) {
       try{
        if($connection != null){
           $this->Connection = $connection;
        }else{
            throw new Exception('Connection is null. COuld not process further');
        }
       }catch(Exception $ex){
          echo $ex->getMessage();
          exit;
       }
    }
    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }
    public function insertUserRecordForSignup(){
        $sql=mysqli_query($this->Connection,"select * from cn_user_info order by user_id desc");
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't be visible in subsequent methods of that class, you have to pass it as an argument - yes, but you also need to make it a property of that class.

Comment: Thanks @Qirel. Updated it

Comment: Yay! @Qirel Helps everyone :)